Google app script using digikey api error 404 invalid resource path
Description of the issue
So I'm making a google app script that does a keyword search with the digikey api, searching with the manufacturer part number i enter into a column on google sheets and grabbing the product description, detailed description, and digikey part number and populating them in specific columns in said google sheet. the problem im getting is that i keep getting error 404 trying to do a keyword search with the manufacturer part number. I also tried going into the digikey api documentation and trying to manually use the url by populating my info into certain fields and that told me my bearer token is invalid even though its seemingly working in my google app script(which uses javascript)
Here is the code for my script in javascript, fair warning its 120 lines. to recreate the problem im having you have to make a google sheet then open google app scripts and enter the following code into the code.gs, and the next thing i put into the appscript.json.
The Error im getting:
Info
Response Code: 404
Info
Response Text: { "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4", "title": "Not Found", "status": 404, "detail": "Invalid resource path. Requested resource is not available", "instance": "", "correlationId": "a9af05c5-0d9a-427e-d6f1-c53e9bc7eb5f", "ValidationErrors": {} }
Info
Error fetching product info: { "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4", "title": "Not Found", "status": 404, "detail": "Invalid resource path. Requested resource is not available", "instance": "", "correlationId": "a9af05c5-0d9a-427e-d6f1-c53e9bc7eb5f", "ValidationErrors": {} }
Code is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10qZS-SJ2PH8D-e5Hr774IKb4xNC-vi07/view?usp=sharing

Questions should be self-contained contained. Please add a [mcve]
